# postgres inner join based on if else statemnet

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I am having a situation in which if a flag is true then inner join a table else no join required.

```
SELECT     ti.upc, 
              ti.quantity, 
              ti.return_type, 
              ti.amount, 
              ti.transaction_date, 
              ti.transaction_time, 
              ti.location_id
   FROM       transaction_item ti 
   IF _user = true THEN
   INNER JOIN user_location ul 
   ON         ul.location_id=ti.location_id 
   AND      ul.user_id=_user_id 
   AND        ul.location_id=_location_id
   END IF; 
   WHERE        ti.transaction_date BETWEEN _start_date::date AND  _end_date::date
   AND        ti.upc IS NOT NULL as ti
```

Comment: Sounds as if you want an outer join. Where does this `_user` thing come from?

Comment: it is a dynamic variable passed by a function call

Comment: Just a note. To be direct on what others have implied. There is no **IF** in sql. There is some optionality  provided by CASE, but that's for "selection" not process direction (logic flow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change your `inner join` to a `left join` and add the check on the variable to the `on` conditions. Then, the `where` clause can filter out rows for which a join should have happened but did not succeed:

```
SELECT     
    ti.upc, 
    ti.quantity, 
    ti.return_type, 
    ti.amount, 
    ti.transaction_date, 
    ti.transaction_time, 
    ti.location_id
FROM transaction_item ti 
LEFT JOIN user_location ul 
    ON  _user = true
    AND ul.location_id=ti.location_id 
    AND ul.user_id=_user_id 
    AND ul.location_id=_location_id
WHERE    
    ti.transaction_date BETWEEN _start_date::date AND  _end_date::date
    AND ti.upc IS NOT NULL
    AND NOT (_user = true AND ul.location_id IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not using any data from  `user_location`, so I would recommend:

```
SELECT ti.upc, ti.quantity, ti.return_type,  ti.amount, 
       ti.transaction_date, ti.transaction_time, ti.location_id
FROM ransaction_item ti 
WHERE (_user <> true OR
       EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM user_location ul 
               WHERE ul.location_id = ti.location_id AND
                     ul.user_id = _user_id AND
                     ul.location_id = _location_id
              )
      ) AND
      ti.transaction_date BETWEEN _start_date::date AND _end_date::date AND
      ti.upc IS NOT NULL;
```

To me "conditional join" seems hard to follow.  However, conditional filters in the `WHERE` clause are pretty easy to follow.